# the title in the overflow menu item is not appearing

Tags: android, menu, overflow, toolbar, title

so, the overflow menu appears in the application, but the title the string is not shown in the menu items. I have tried many things but I couldn't figure out a way to make it appear.

for example I tried overriding `onPrepareOptionsMenu` function. It doesn't work.

please help me out guys

this is my `options_menu.xml` file

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
        <menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    
        <item
            android:id="@+id/aboutFragment"
            android:title="About"
            android:menuCategory="secondary"
            app:showAsAction="never"/>    
       </menu>
```

and here is how I am inflating it my `MainActivity.kt` file

```
override fun onCreateOptionsMenu(menu: Menu?): Boolean {
    menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.options_menu, menu)
    return true
}
```

Comment: Please try to do proper R&D before asking question. It seems that you didn't do proper research for the answer of your question. I have given answer from an existing question. Please check.

Comment: The problems is not with the schema address. It is similar with the one you suggested.

Comment: Sorry from my side as I did mistake in understanding.

Comment: Can you please check [this](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ActionBarSherlock/issues/945) link. It might help.